# Memory size of logical variable

Tags: r, memory

I'm working on a large `data.frame` (e.g. 500k rows/observations, 2500 columns/features). Every feature is `Boolean`, so only two values are possible `TRUE` / `FALSE`.

After noticing a extremely high RAM usage I checked the following:

```
myVar = TRUE
class(myVar)
# [1] "logical"
object.size(myVar)
# 48 bytes
```

I'm used to `char`-sized `bool`s from `C` taking `8Bit = 1Byte`. Can someone  elaborate where this massive overhead comes from or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There are NO variables in **R**, everything is vector (or list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare below:

```
object.size(logical())
# 48 bytes

object.size(TRUE)
# 40 bytes
```

See post by Hadley about [Memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) for more info.

> Every length 0 vector occupies 40 bytes of memory.